# Analyze SSL certificate programmatically or via commandline

Tags: java, c++, c, objective-c, ssl

I'ld like to analyze the certificate of a given url and get some details of it. Do you know any ways to do this? A command-line tool can be something like `downloadSSLCert https://my.funny.url/ > certFile` and then analyzing it for e.g. the fingerprint of the cert. It can be a command line utility, a C/C++/Objective-C or Java code and will be used on osx >= 10.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make an SSL connection from the command line thus:

```
echo '' | openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443
```

The output will contain the X.509 cert in base64 encoding.

To view further details,

```
... | openssl x509 -fingerprint -text
```

If you *only* want the fingerprint, omit the "`-text`" flag and add "`-out /dev/null`".

Comment: +1 I'd like more:  openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 | less cuz the output may be extensive

Comment: Thanks! And is there a way to get the fingerprints out of this infos? Google for example has a sha1 fingerprint starting with AB:BE. How to get the fingerprints?

Comment: @Victor - the OP appears to want a non-interactive method - less is an interactive cmd.

Comment: @Alnitak: Thanks, with the option -sha1, I can read the informations, I need!

Comment: You can use `-noout` instead of `-out /dev/null`.